# Keeping track of a user's login time in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.8

Im new to development.

Right now I'm trying to figure out how I can keep track of each user's individual logged in times. Users can of course logout of the app but they can also close the tab or browser and I dont know how to controll all that.

Im using laravel 5.8 and vuejs.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Use SQL to register in a DB the logins and logouts...

You cannot detect when a user closes their browser or navigates off your site using PHP, but you can use a JS code that calls a php file with a SQL query in order to do it.

Comment: I would recommend starting with learning the basics of web development.  Then, when you have one or multiple specific questions, return here with more details on those questions.  Things to include in future questions would be: (1) code examples you have already attempted, (2) error messages you receive or other details about what is failing with your code, (3) the expected behavior of your code, and (4) the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Typically one does time tracking by having some javascript ping the time tracker every minute (or whatever you want your granularity to be).  When the tracker updates stop, the user isn't connected.  Even that isn't all that satisfactory if you consider users who just leave the window open and walk away, so more complex solutions involve detecting idleness based on recorded inputs ... it gets complicated.

Comment: 2 ways would be using a presence channel or really just use the javascript's onbeforeunload. Depending on how precise it should be